# Div not hiding with media queries and display:none;

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a div that I want to hide on small mobile devices as it would slide under the logo.  I have other elements that work without issue, but this one I am having issues with it hiding.  I want to hide the div id "tagline" but it isn't hiding.

```
<div class="container">
<div id="logo"><a href="../index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Nucleo-Logo','','../images/logo-over.png',1)"><img id="Nucleo-Logo" src="../images/logo.png" alt="Nucleo Fitness, Rapid City, SD" /></a> </div>
<div id="tagline"><img src="../images/get_to_the_core.png" alt="Get to the core."/>  <br/><h4>605-430-1418</a></h4></div>
</div>
```

Now, my CSS looks like this:

```
#tagline{float:right; z-index:1; display:inline-block; margin-top:-75px; margin-right:15%;}
@media(max-with:600px) {
#tagline{display:none; visibility:hidden; clear:both;}}
```

Comment: Maybe if you do `@media screen and (max-width:600px) {` ... note you misspelled `width`

Comment: inspect it in developer tools, might be that another style has priority over display property you can try display:none !important;

Comment: Voted to close as main issue was a typo

Answer (score 1):

- `max-with` should be `max-width`
- In your HTML you have `</a>` but it's never opened (after `605-430-1418`)

```css
#tagline {
    float: right;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -75px;
    margin-right: 15%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #tagline {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="../index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Nucleo-Logo','','../images/logo-over.png',1)"><img id="Nucleo-Logo" src="../images/logo.png" alt="Nucleo Fitness, Rapid City, SD" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="tagline">
        <img src="../images/get_to_the_core.png" alt="Get to the core." /><br/>
        <h4>605-430-1418</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```